# Can long/heavy lenses deform the lens mount?

Tags: equipment-protection, telephoto, equipment-damage

I recently got a Tamron 150-600mm lens, which gets to ~33cm (13') long and weighs about 2 kg (4.3 lb). When shooting hand-held with the lens, I obviously always support the lens with my hand.

When walking around with the lens mounted on my 600D or 30D, should I always support the lens or is it safe to let the camera/lens dangle from my shoulder strap?

Answer (score 3):

In a scenario like this, I would try and mitigate the risk of mount deformation by using a sling strap that secures to the tripod mount (something like a Black Rapid strap), but fasten it to a tripod collar on the lens rather than the one on the camera. This will maintain the best balance of weight, and I personally find sling straps much more comfortable.

Comment: Good advice but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Caleb Guess I was just trying to say 'if in doubt, don't risk it'.

Comment: @Caleb Sure it answers the question. With such a heavy lens "always support the lens" by using a strap connected to the lens' tripod collar instead of to the camera.

Comment: @MichaelClark Given this answer, how could one *know* when it's safe to let the lens hang from the mount and when it's not? If someone else chimes in with "I hang a heavier lens than that off my 30D with no problem," how could the OP decide whether Pakman's or the other guy's gut feeling is the right answer? What's needed here is definitive information about the strength of the EF mount.

Comment: @Caleb I totally see where you're coming from, but from all the hunting I've done I haven't been able to find any definitive information on the strength of the lens mount. There was [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52394/are-there-any-official-specifications-regarding-the-torque-for-camera-mounts) question the other day about torque on lens mounts, but the general consensus is that no-one really knows, or at least the manufacturers aren't forthcoming with this information. Edit: Just noticed, that question was actually asked 3 years ago, not the other day :S

Comment: @Caleb [This](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52394/are-there-any-official-specifications-regarding-the-torque-for-camera-mounts) is the question from yesterday.

Comment: Many lenses that large also have strap lugs attached to the body of the lens or to the side of the tripod collar.