# Can a flash be too heavy to be used directly on the hot shoe?

Tags: hotshoe-flash

I've bought a Yongnuo YN-560 IV which weighs 350g and is quite massive. It has a hot shoe connector, but I'm worried that attaching it to the camera (Canon 77D) is unsafe, especially when shooting in portrait mode. Are my worries justified or is the hot shoe stronger than I imagine?

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52394/are-there-any-official-specifications-regarding-the-torque-for-camera-mounts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a flash be too heavy to be used directly on the hot shoe?

Yes, a flash could be so large and heavy that it could not be used directly on the camera's hot shoe.

> I've bought a Yongnuo YN-560 IV which weighs 350g... but I'm worried that attaching it to the camera (Canon 77D) is unsafe... Are my worries justified?

No, the Yongnuo YN-560 IV, at 350g, is hardly too "massive" to be used directly on a camera's hot shoe. The Canon 600EX-RT tips the scales at 425 grams and is regularly used on the hot shoes of many Canon cameras with no ill effects.