# I took up my camera by the lens when it was on a tripod... Will it cause any damage?

Tags: dslr, lens-mount, equipment-damage

I took up my camera by the lens when the camera was attached to a tripod. Will it cause any damage?

Comment: what camera, and what lens were you using, out of curiosity?

Comment: Nikon D5300 with kit lens...

Comment: If you feel there might have been damage, the best course would be to test to see if there was any damage. We cannot tell from here.

Comment: Related: [Can I hang a heavy lens vertically from the body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/117125/15871) is also concerned with how much force the lens mount connection between camera and lens can withstand.

Comment: @Tech, you can edit your original question/post to add details and missing information.  StackExchange tries to get you good quality answers to good quality questions so it's better if the details are in your question instead of in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

No, at least not on the camera. The lens mount of the camera is designed to support the weight of the camera (and some accessories). When used with big heavy lenses (anything bigger than 200mm) the lens supports the camera and not the other way around (a tripod is attached to the lens).

Damage to the lens is quite unlikely, too.

Comment: Some tripods might weigh enough to put more stress on the mount connection between camera and lens when the camera and tripod are picked up by holding the lens than all but the heaviest lenses would when the camera and lens are supported only by holding the camera..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will not cause damage maybe it will, but if is a risky way of picking it up why risk it?

It made you come here and ask this, so you did not feel comfortable in doing it. So just pick it up by the camera instead.

Strange question to be asked to be honest. You felt it was not right, the same way we would probably feel. Changing the way you pick up the camera is not a life changer so, just pick it up in a way that does not make you question yourself if you are doing things right or not.

And why would you prefer to pick it up by the lens anyway? If you were looking for: "Its fine man I do it all the time".

and even if anyone does this, each camera can be more fragile in its own way. so the obvious answer would always be: just pick it up normally.

Comment: I did this only one time by mistake...

Comment: Ok you did it, but did it break? no, not at all so. You come here and ask if its broken? You know better than we do.